# MS Access how reset/clear all data (not only tables) from db

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm on Access db (2010) and having working mdb on Site A I need to ship it to new client outside the company, just leaving some lookup tables (3 our of 5).
I thought that I did my job deleting all tables, checking all forms, and qry, all clean no any personal info present in tables or other objects.

But then our QA opened mdb in notepad and found some personal data readable enough so I need to figure out now how to clean it. This is just part of it, and I see a lot of those inside the file using notepad.
Please help me to reset it ? what is the trick ?? Where is that data . Tx all

```
  ÿþ2005-05-28-102117T @ b     ÿþSpearsÿþLarryÿþPeronaÿþLauraÿþP.O. Box 8ÿþTucsonÿþ87523ÿ
```

Answer (score 1):

Access keeps a lot of temporary data stored.

If you want to remove it, do a *[Compact & Repair](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2)*. This essentially moves all objects to a fresh database, clearing all temporary data.